# Why my event listener isnt being triggered?

Tags: php, laravel, events, backend, event-listener

I want to send an email after a receipt has been created to the user. I have a Receipt controller which creates a controller which then fires an event Receipt Created Event which should fire a listener Send Receipt Notification which should send a mail(I have tried it with a job first).
Code:
Receipt Created Event:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Events;
 
use App\Models\Racun;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 
class ReceiptCreatedEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
 
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
 
    public function __construct(public Racun $receipt)
    {
 
        $this->receipt = $receipt;
    }
 
    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('channel-name'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Listeners;
 
use App\Events\ReceiptCreatedEvent;
use App\Mail\ReceiptCreatedNotification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
 
class SendReceiptNotification
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
 
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(ReceiptCreatedEvent $event): void
    {   info("This is the receipt: " . $event->receipt);
        Mail::to($event->receipt->user->email)->send(new ReceiptCreatedNotification($event->receipt, $event->receipt->user));
        //SendMailJob::dispatch($event->receipt);
    }
}
```

Receipt Controller:

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Events\ReceiptCreatedEvent;
use App\Mail\ReceiptCreatedNotification;
use App\Models\Artikal;
use App\Models\Racun;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
 
class RacunController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function ajaxStore(Request $request){
        $this->authorize('storeReceipt', auth()->user());
        $data = $request->all();
 
        $racun = Racun::create(
            [
                'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
                'hladnjaca_id' => $data['hladnjaca_id'],
                'artikal_id' => $data['artikal'],
                'datum' => now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'ulaz_gajbi' => $data['ulaz'],
                'izlaz_gajbi' => $data['izlaz'],
                'bruto' => $data['bruto'],
                'neto' => $data['neto'],
                'cena_po_kg_pdv' => Artikal::find($data['artikal'])->cena_sa_pdvom,
                'cena_po_kg_bez_pdv' => Artikal::find($data['artikal'])->cena_bez_pdva,
                'ukupno_cena_pdv' => $data['iznos_sa_pdvom'],
                'ukupno_cena_bez_pdv'=> $data['iznos_bez_pdva']
            ]
        );
       //Mail::to($racun->user->email)->send(new ReceiptCreatedNotification($racun, $racun->user));
 
        $response = [
            'message' => 'success'
        ];
       ReceiptCreatedEvent::dispatch($racun);
       return Response::json($response);
    }
}
```

Registration of event and listener :

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
 
       SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    ReceiptCreatedEvent::class => [
        SendReceiptNotification::class,
    ],
];
```

The mail works, I have tried it with no listener so its not problem in that. The listener isnt firing so theres nothing in the logs, I have tried info() helper, but yet nothing...

Comment: In the event do a dd($receipt), to see if that is received. Then in the listener in the constructor do the exact same, but then for $event

Comment: In constructor event I did info() and it worked it logged the $receipt in logs correctly. But listener wont work, I have put the info() in constructor and in handle method, the listener just isnt being called. I really dont know what could be the problem...

Comment: I have solved it. I dont know what the problem was but surely started working after running bunch of artisan commands, I believe php artisan clear -compiled done the job but not sure. Composer -dump autoload was not the one(done it 10 times). Anyways thanks for the help